# How do I convert $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + ...$ to summation notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I can convert $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... = -\frac {1}{12}$ to summation notation: $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n = -\frac {1}{12}$$ But, how can I convert the following series to summation notation: $$1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + ... = \frac 12$$ I tried using the WolframAlpha Summation calculator (I input $1 - 1 + 1 - 1$ until some point), but it kept returning 0. One idea I have is to use summation notation without any bounds, but I doubted myself on that.

Is there a way to convert the above series to summation notation?

Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: What about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$?

Comment: You have a sum of alternating positive and negative ones.... note that $(-1)^n $ bounces from positive to negative as we go from even to odd integers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + ...=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(\pi n)$

Also, $\sum \limits_{n = 1}^\infty n = -\frac {1}{12}$ in the context of $\zeta(-1)$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) for more information.

Comment: also $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}sin(\pi/2+\pi n)$ if for some reason we're coming up with fun ways.

Comment: @noah very interesting!